# No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I keep getting this error for the declarative pipeline script in Jenkins.

```
No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps
```

My script is like this

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have Jenkins version 2.19.4. Hopefully i have installed all the required plugins. Why do i get this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed the latest plugins, 1.2. I had the same issue that after I upgraded the **Pipeline: Model Definition** to **1.2** my pipelines stopped working. I was unable to downgrade the plugins (this broke evertyhing) and was forced to upgrade from 2.46.1 to 2.73.1, only after this I was able to run the pipelines again.

Anyway, I would recommend to upgrade as other codes that were not working for me for some reason in 2.46 are now working.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the Jenkins Pipeline plugin. I had this issue on a new instance of Jenkins and this plugin solved my 'No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps' issue.

Below is the link:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin